# Bigquery timezone conversion error while parsing date

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to parse and convert date time using below statement. But, its producing wrong result.

```
SELECT
SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', '9/6/21 7:22 AM',"US/Central")
```

Also, how to handle daylight savings with bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery *does* handle DST.  It might help if you parsed your date in the modern era.  I also tend to use city names to be sure I'm getting the local time:

```
SELECT SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p', '9/6/21 7:22 AM', "US/Central"),
       SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p', '9/6/21 7:22 AM', 'America/Chicago')
```

Note that this produces a date this year rather than in the year 21 AD.